# Lossless 10-bit colorspace (yuvj420p) video output

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, encoding

Using **GoPro** footage which are in **10-bit color** space (**yuvj420p**), and using Blender as a video editor, the output seems to always be in 8-bit color space.

**How can I preserve the 10-bit color space?**

Tried:

- Output: AVI RAW
- Output: H.264 + Encoding Format: H.264 + [X] Lossless
- Output: H.264 + Encoding Format: AVI + Codec: H.264 + [X] Lossless
- Output: H.264 + Encoding Format: Quicktime + Codec: H.264 + [X] Lossless
- Output: H.264 + Encoding Format: AVI + Codec: HuffYUV
- [Float color space in sequencer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57528/whats-the-convert-float-checkbox-in-the-vse-for/57535#57535)

No matter these, in the end `ffprobe` always shows it's not anymore in `yuvj420p` but in `yuv420p` (or what should be another 8-bit color space format). This results in **washed out** colors visible on **HDR monitors** (barely noticeable on older monitors).

Similar questions without good answers yet:

- [Lossless compression for video with audio](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/lossless-compression-for-video-with-audio)
- [What setting should I use to keep the same quality of video file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50045/what-setting-should-i-use-to-keep-the-same-quality-of-video-file)
- [⚓ T44827 Video sequencer does not recognize pixel format 'yuvj420p' correctly](https://developer.blender.org/T44827)

Note: Input video file format (from `ffprobe`):

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8217 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
```

Comment: Hmm, I have this dim recollection that the VSE is 8bit. Try enabling each strips color management in properties.

Comment: @3pointedit In Sequencer for the video strip (trying with a single strip) I've enabled *Colors: Convert to Float* and tried various *Input Color*. Still having no `yuvj420p` in the end.

Comment: The difference between yuvj420p and yuv420p isn't the bit depth, but the range. yuv420p has the range 16-235 whereas yuvj420p has the full range, 0-255. Moreover, your input file is encoded with profile _High_, which doesn't support 10-bit. You'll need _High 10_, _High 4:2:2_ or _High 4:4:4 Predictive_ for 10-bit support. So basically your input seems to be 8-bit, and the colour loss is likely caused by the reduced range rather than by fewer bits. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the VSE to use yuvj420p, so I won't add this as an answer.

Comment: 3PointEdit wins another one; VSE is *always* 8 BPP.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley Thanks for clarifying the format. Would you know which lossless codec is likely to have the largest color range? I can always force ffmpeg to use uyvj420p later and that might do the trick.

Comment: Honestly, I don't encode to video directly from Blender. I do mostly stills, and with the few animations I do, I usually save the individual frames as images, which I then postprocess outside Blender before encoding with ffmpeg.

Comment: Apparently h265 supports lossless with the x265 encoder. Might aswell give it a shot.
https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/lossless.html

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

When working on footage, it is always most prudent to operate on the frame level, with controlled decoding to the file format you choose. Codecs always have been and always will be an awful choice.

Currently in Blender, *all* codecs via the VSE (and otherwise I believe) are decoded using the FFMPEG call that converts them to an 8 bit buffer.

So, decode outside to a suitable 16 bit container such as TIFF, then properly linearize the results via a controlled transform.

Also, “8 bit” is not a colour space, nor is “10 bit”, nor is “float color space”.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question here, it looks like it's possible by rendering as PNG then using:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 500/21 -i %d.png -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -c:a copy output.mkv
```

See https://youtu.be/Ng8bS2iPS1w?t=922

Answer (score 0):

As other have said convert to png and back but your answer makes a 20 b/px file from a 12 b/px file which is wasteful;

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts 2>&1 | grep -P "yuvj?420p |FLAGS|yuv422p10le"
FLAGS NAME            NB_COMPONENTS BITS_PER_PIXEL BIT_DEPTHS
IO... yuv420p                3             12      8-8-8
IO... yuvj420p               3             12      8-8-8
IO... yuv422p10le            3             20      10-10-10
```